# Setting div visibility on image click

Tags: image, html, onclick

So I've got an image that inside a tag, and I've also got a div that is centred in the middle of the screen.

How do I make this div invisible until the image is clicked?

Preview of page when the div is visible: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8XZe.jpg]

So that added to cart is a div in the middle of the screen. I want that to only show up when the "Add to cart" button has been clicked.

I want the div to go away again after 2 seconds. Transitions would be nice (eg fade into visibility), but I don't mind.

Comment: I've tried the only answer there, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the display of the div to none and do a onclick event for the image which sets the display of the div to block. I would recommend using JQuery to add in any transitions or animations.

Something like (without animations):

```
<div id="cart" style="display:none">

</div>
<img src="imgsource" onClick="document.getElementById('cart').style.display = 'block'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Had to use jQuery.

In the < head> :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".addtocart").click(function(){
    $(".addedcartbg").fadeIn(500);
    $(".addedcartbg").delay(1000);
    $(".addedcartbg").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

In the < body> :

```
<div class="addedcartbg" style="display:none"><div class="addedcart"> Successfully added to cart. </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

html

```
<div class="hide">
// put content here
</div>
<img class="hide-show" src="site.com/image.png" alt=""/>
```

js

```
$(function(){
 $('.hide-show').bind('click',function(){
    $('.hide').fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);

    });
});
```